# Square Integrable Functions Formula

Tags: fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-series

[image]

The book reads as follows:

"Let $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ be square integrable functions defined on [$a , b$]. First we note that it follows from the elementary inequality

$|ab| \le 1/2 (a^2 + b^2)$

that the function $|ab|$ is integrable."

**Where does this function come from? How do I derive it? Does it have to do with the Schwarz Inequality? What does this equation imply about square integrable functions and absolutely integrable functions?**

Comment: [AMGM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Comment: Your comment sir is greatly appreciated! The best of luck to your endeavors in Michigan!

Comment: But, what does this imply about the relationship between square integrable functions and absolutely integrable functions?

Comment: Do you know what it means for $\varphi$ to be square-integrable?

Comment: Whoops! Never mind! You have corrected me yet again Tyler!